# The public is cautioned about/of pickpockets

Tags: prepositions

> The public is cautioned ________ pickpockets.

Can someone fill in the blank with the correct answer. I'm not sure whether it is 'of' or 'about'.

Comment: Idiomatically it would more likely be ***warned against** pickpockets*.

Answer (score 1):

This is the better choice:

> The public is cautioned *about* pickpockets.

***Cautioned of*** sounds awkward, though ***warned of*** sounds OK to me.

As FumbleFingers said, ***warned against*** is a good option, as well as ***warned about***.